# Symfony, RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I would like someone to tell me how I can solve my problem regarding the RabbitmQ consumer in the symfiny project, the situation is as follows:
I have a library called Shared written by me, this library contains publisher.php, consumer.php this class is implemented in the microservice B, in the listener that listens if there is no header then it activates the consumer to check if microservice A does not send this message with a jwt token. and here is my problem because when I send a publisher from microservice A to Mikroservice B, microservice B still works in while. do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

```
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false);

    echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";

    //! The callback will be executed when the consumer sees that the message has arrived
    //! why is my app crashing? because when a message arrives, he continues to listen for the next one and in this way nothing will be displayed to me

    $callback = function ($msg) use ($channel) {
        echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->body, "\n";

        sleep(substr_count($msg->body, '.'));
        echo " [x] Done\n";
        $msg->ack();
        $channel->basic_cancel($msg->getConsumerTag());
    };

    $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $channel->basic_consume('task_queue', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

    while ($channel->is_consuming()) {
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question : Why dont u use Symfony messenger component which is exactly a component that doest what your trying to achieve homemade ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html

Comment: hi, i'm using two microservices and my own library called shared , do you think a good way would be to define a class command in Shared, then in microservice 1 put the command and in the other microservice use a handler to receive the message? I thought this would be a good solution, but I need microservice 1 to send more than one microservice jwt token.

Comment: I kind of agree with @ThomasL, as I understand you need Microservice A to publish in a specific queue some messages (with the JWT) and then consume them in this specific queue with Microservice B. As I see it, you must do the same (or similar configuration) in both microservices and just define and execute the consumers in Microservice B (instead of Microservice A), which can be done using Symfony Messenger, or did I get something wrong?

Comment: @DaniPilot, ok i use that and right now i thinking how i can store my sended message so that every message:consume receives a message that is embedded in rabbitmq and does not expire?

Comment: @DaniPilot how should look my config for send the message to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Micheal841 using symfony messenger the messages do not expire by default. In both microservices you have to define the same queue in the messenger.yaml configuration, you can do this defining a transport and then routing the message into it (check the Symfony Messenger documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#prioritized-transports). Microservice A will just dispatch messages to the queue and Microservice B will consume them (and therefore have the consumer class implemented),